# Error in using MLlib function ALS in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have  read from a file like this:

```
val ratingText = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/rec_data/processed_data/ratings/000000_0")
```

Used the following function to parse this data:

```
def parseRating(str: String): Rating= {
      val fields = str.split(",")
      Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).trim.toInt, fields(2).trim.toDouble)
}
```

And created a rdd, which is then split into different RDDs

```
val ratingsRDD = ratingText.map(x=>parseRating(x)).cache()

val splits = ratingsRDD.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), 0L)

val trainingRatingsRDD = splits(0).cache()
```

Used the training RDD to create a model as follows:

```
val model = (new ALS().setRank(20).setIterations(10) .run(trainingRatingsRDD))
```

I get the following error in the last command

```
16/10/28 01:03:44 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
16/10/28 01:03:44 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
16/10/28 01:03:46 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
16/10/28 01:03:46 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
```

Edit: T. Gaweda's suggestion helped in removing the errors, but I am still getting the following warning:

```
16/10/28 01:53:59 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 60:
[rdd_420_0]
16/10/28 01:54:00 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 61:
[rdd_421_0]
```

And I think this has resulted in an empty model , because the next step is resulting in the following error:

val topRecsForUser = model.recommendProducts(4276736,3)

Error is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It's only a warning. Spark uses BLAS to perform calculations. BLAS has native implementations and JVM implementation, the native one is more optimized / faster. However, you must install native library individually.

Without this configuration the warning message will appear and Spark will use JVM implementation of BLAS. Results should be the same, maybe calculated quite slower.

[Here](http://159.203.217.164/blas-libraries-in-mllib/) you've got description what is BLAS and how to configure it, for example on Cent OS is should be only: `yum install openblas lapack`

Comment: Thanks @T. Gaweda,that worked wonderfully in removing the warnings, but following errors persist. Can you please have a look;:val model = (new ALS().setRank(20).setIterations(10) .run(trainingRatingsRDD))
16/10/28 01:53:59 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 60:
[rdd_420_0]
16/10/28 01:54:00 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 61:
[rdd_421_0]
model: org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel = org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel@4a853a7d

Comment: Also, after this when I use val topRecsForUser = model.recommendProducts(4276736,3), I get an error saying                          java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
Does it mean that the model is empty? Please help!

Comment: It's a problem with your code - you're trying to predict with user id that not exists in model - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488328/mllib-matrixfactorizationmodel-recommendproductsuser-num-failing-on-some-user

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, T Gaweda! You were right